# find dynamically added controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, dynamic

I'm adding dropdownlists to my page depending on a amount of database entries and when I press the button I want to get the selected values in each dropdownlist.

I tried this

```
foreach(DropDownList a in Form.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>())
{
    Response.Write(a.SelectedValue);
}
```

but it doesn't find any dropdownlist on the page. Below is the code I use to add the dorpdownlists.

```
protected void Page_Init()
{
    string product = Request.QueryString["product"];
    foreach (productoption r in dbcon.GetOption(product))
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cel1 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cel2 = new TableCell();
        DropDownList dropdown1 = new DropDownList();
        dropdown1.CssClass = "productdropdown";
        foreach (suboption f in dbcon.GetSubOption(r.ProductOptionID))
        {
            dropdown1.Items.Add(f.SubOptionName + " +$" +f.SubOptionPrice);
        }
        cel1.Text = "<b>" + r.OptionName + "</b>";
        cel2.Controls.Add(dropdown1);
        row.Cells.Add(cel1);
        row.Cells.Add(cel2);
        Table1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    TableRow row2 = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
    Button cartbutton = new Button();
    cartbutton.ID = product;
    cartbutton.CssClass = "btn_addcart";
    cartbutton.Click += cartbutton_OnClick;
    cartbutton.Text = "Add to cart";
    cell3.Controls.Add(cartbutton);
    row2.Cells.Add(cell3);
    Table1.Rows.Add(row2);
}
```

Comment: Not found `Form.Controls.Add(dropdown1)` in page_init. Where you did you write code to add `DropDownList` on you page.

Comment: I always found that when creating dynamic controls (creating at runtime), the best way to reference those controls later is when you create them, add them to a private local dictionary, and then make the name of the control something that you will at least know the pattern to so that you can use that as the key.  If you are creating multiple controls of the same type, use a for loop and use String.Format("{0}{1}", "controlType", loopVariable).

Comment: @Sameer good answer in page_init view state isnt loaded yet.

Comment: @Sameer @Liran Inside the looping there's a Table1.Rows.Add(row); and probably it is an `<asp:Table />` placed between the `<form></form>` tags on .aspx page.

Comment: Try this it may work `foreach (TabelRow row in Table1.Rows)
{
 DropDownList a = (DropDownList)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
 Response.Write(a.SelectedValue);
}`

Comment: @Sameer
thanks that works, I just need a way to check if the row is a dropdownlist because at this moment I get an error if the row doesn't contain a dropdownlist

Comment: @user3025852 I add sample code in answer please check. and if it solve you problem vote for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (TabelRow row in Table1.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells.Count > 0)
    {
        if (row.Cells[1].Controls.Count > 0 && row.Cells[1].Controls[0].GetType() ==  typeof(DropDownList))
        {
            Response.Write(a.SelectedValue); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should make a function that looks for a control type in a `ControlCollection` and returns a list of found controls. Something like that:

```
    public List<T> GetControlsOfType<T>(ControlCollection controls)
    {
        List<T> ret = new List<T>();
        try
        {
            foreach (Control control in controls)
            {             
                    if (control is T)
                        ret.Add((T)((object)control));                            
                    else if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
                        ret.AddRange(GetControlsOfType<T>(control.Controls));                  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log the exception
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

and then you can get all `DropDownList` like that:

```
List<DropDownList> ret = GetControlsOfType<DropDownList>(this.Page.Controls);
```

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

**`You should be adding controls inside another control for example a panel`**
**`Also you dont need to define controls at page init, you can do that at page load and they will retain their value`**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    loadControls();
 }
```

//For Instance lets take a dropdownlist and add it to a panel named testpanel

```
Protected void loadControls()
{
  DropdownList ddlDynamic = new DropdownList();
  //give this control an id
  ddlDynamic.Id = "ddlDynamic1"; // this  id is very important as the control can be found with same id
  //add data to dropdownlist
  //adding to the panel
  testpanel.Controls.Add(ddlDynamic);
}
```

//Now we have to find this control on post back for instance a button click

```
protected void btnPreviousSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       //this will find the control here
       //we will you the same id used while creating control
       DropdownList ddlDynamic1 = testpanel.FindControl("ddlDynamic1") as DropdownList;
       //can resume your operation here
     }
```